# Как правильно увеличивать/уменьшать размер динамического массива С?

Tags: c, динамические-массивы

Вопрос выше. Мне известно, что нужно увеличивать/уменьшать размер памяти, выделенной под массив в *k* раз (как правило, в 2 раза), когда фактический размер доходит до соответствующего значения. Но есть ли какие-либо требования по эффективности выделения памяти в этом случае в отношении начальной инициализации, т.е. нужно ли при первом выделении памяти устанавливать размер массива в значение, например, кратное количеству битов в типе char или таких требований нет и на эффективность кода это никак не повлияет. Прошу прояснить этот момент.

Comment: Память выделяют под элементы определенного типа. Странно будет выделить под массив n байт  кратное, скажем, 3, если собераетесь в массиве хранить int.

Comment: Для начала, выделить память (не важно, динамическую или нет) в количестве **не кратном количеству БИТОВ в char** ***невозможно***).  На эффективность кода (в смысле доступа к памяти) в первую очередь влияет как часто будет происходить вытеснение измененных данных из кэша. Но предметно говорить об этом можно только рассматривая конкретный алгоритм и набор данных. Во всех остальных случаях это будут рассуждения из серии -- *"лучше быть богатым и здоровым, чем ..."*. (Практическая рекомендация (для современных ОС) -- чем реже вы вызываете realloc (конечно, в рамках разумного), тем лучше)